# CSS 3 Pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this(image attached) by pure CSS without using any images. Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you should make a main wrapping `div` and create 3 different elements into it like `span` and decorate it with `background-color` and custom `height` and `width`. To make them stand in one line you can use different ways but I suggest to use flexbox as I did in the below snippet:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

div > span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

div > span:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

div > span.purple {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #6f2580;
}

div > span.green {
  background-color: #16968d;
}

div > span.pink {
  background-color: #c4297e;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="purple"></span>
  <span class="green"></span>
  <span class="pink"></span>
</div>
```

EDIT: here an example with a title for each of the dash lines.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

div > h4 > span {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

div > h4:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

div > h4 > span.purple {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #6f2580;
}

div > h4 > span.green {
  background-color: #16968d;
}

div > h4 > span.pink {
  background-color: #c4297e;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>title
    <span class="purple"></span>
  </h4>
  <h4>title
    <span class="green"></span>
  </h4>
  <h4>title
    <span class="pink"></span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks SMAKSS. I am wondering if a title can be added on top of that line.

Comment: Actually I was trying to achieve this with pseudo-elements as Zohir posted. Can we do that? I am wondering.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not achievable with `after` and `before` for more than two dash lines.

Comment: Humm..seems like so. Is it achievable with SVG instead?

Comment: Yes sure, you can produce a single SVG for the whole thing or different one for every one of them. But I'm not sure what exactly you looking for!

Comment: I am looking for the above design without using any span or anything. It's a multicolor dashed line with different dash width

Comment: As I mentioned before there is no possible way (as far as I know) to create multiple dash lines with pseudo-elements because there is only 2 possible directive (`after` and `before`) for this cause.

Answer (score 1):

sir :)

you can use spans for the blobs. see if you can use the code below.

```css
.blob {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.blob_large {
  min-width: 110px;
}
.blob_purple {
  background: #662d7c;
}
.blob_teal {
  background: #45948d;
}
.blob_pink {
  background: #b53a7c;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  
  <span class="blob blob_large blob_purple"></span>
  <span class="blob blob_teal"></span>
  <span class="blob blob_pink"></span>
  
</div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for aesthetics, consider pseudo-Elements

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #662d7c;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  --background: #45948d;
  --left: 110%;
}

div:after {
  --background: #b53a7c;
  --left: 145%;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--left);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Zohir. It's nice to have with pseudo-elements. But one thing, the small dash lines are not fixed number always. Sometimes it will be more than 2 or 3. Can we achieve that also?